# How to use jQuery drag and drop with paragraph element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to create a customizable paragraph with `JQuery UI`.

here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var given = $("p.given").text();

  var new_given = given.replace(/blank/g, '  <div class="blanks"></div>  ');
  $("p.given").html(new_given);

  function updateDroppables() {
    $("div.blanks").droppable({
      accept: "span.given",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dragedElement = ui.draggable.text();
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        console.log(dropped);
        dropped.hide();
        console.log(dragedElement);
        $(this).replaceWith(
          " <span class='answers'><b class='blue-text' rel='" +
          ui.draggable.attr("rel") +
          "'>" +
          dragedElement +
          "</b> <a href='#' class='material-icons cancel md-16'>highlight_off</a></span> "
        );
      }
    });
  }

  updateDroppables();

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $(document).on("click", "a.cancel", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rel = $(this).prev().attr('rel');
    console.log(rel);

    $(this)
      .parent()
      .replaceWith("<div class='blanks'></div>");
    updateDroppables();
    $('.btn-flat[rel=' + rel + ']').show();
  });
});
```

```css
div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers>b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p><b><i>In the text below some words are missing. Drag words from the box below to the appropriate place in the text. To undo an answer choice, drag the word back to the box below the text.</i></b></p>

<div class="row">
  <p class="given">
    He wants to get a better [blank] and earn more money. Managers set objectives, and decide [blank] their organization can achieve them. A defect can be caused [blank] negligen ce by one of the members of a team.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<br>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">

            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1">the Santee, thDakota</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2">America</span>

            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3">Qatar</span>

            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4">Philippines</span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

This works, but the problem is in the above code draggable components can only add to `[blank]` area. I need to add draggable components inside anywhere of the paragraph `<p>` how can I do it? this is [code pen sample](https://codepen.io/toffler/pen/QBrwMm), you can play and see how above code works

Simple I change above code as follows,

```
$("p.given").droppable({
  accept: "span.given",
  classes: {
    "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
  }
```

but it replaces whole paragraph `<p>` with the dragged component. how can add draggable components to anywhere of the paragraph `<p>` tag.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to be able to insert the content from the draggables as a new paragraph between any other 2 paragraphs in the original text?

Comment: Unsolicited pedantry: We don't manipulate _tags_ with JavaScript. We work with _elements_. In your case, it's a paragraph element. Tags are just how elements are defined in the markup.

Comment: The primary issue here is that Droppable needs to bind to an element. This is why it works for the blanks but not for the other words in the paragraph. The `[blank]` template is replaced with a empty `<span>` element and this is then droppable. You will need to convert the text added by the user into elements, most likely `<span>` that can then become droppable targets. When the user drags a word onto the droppable it can then append after the target the new word.

Comment: @LePhil no sir, I just need drop draggable content to any place of the paragraph (original text). simply say my requirement is the same as the code pen example. problem is its only drag `[blank]` areas. I need to drop any place of the paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the number of things you want to accomplish, there is a whole lot of stuff you need to prepare. Here is a very rough example.

```js
$(function() {
  function textWrapper(str, sp) {
    if (sp == undefined) {
      sp = [
        0,
        0
      ];
    }
    var txt = "<span class='w'>" + str + "</span>";
    if (sp[0]) {
      txt = "&nbsp;" + txt;
    }
    if (sp[1]) {
      txt = txt + "&nbsp;";
    }
    return txt;
  }

  function chunkWords(p) {
    var words = p.split(" ");
    words[0] = textWrapper(words[0], [0, 1]);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words[0].indexOf(".")) {
        words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 0]);
      } else {
        words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 1]);
      }
    }
    return words.join("");
  }

  function makeBtn(tObj) {
    var btn = $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
    }).appendTo(tObj);
    btn.click(function(e) {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  }

  function makeDropText(obj) {
    return obj.droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var txt = ui.draggable.text();
        var newSpan = textWrapper(txt, [1, 0]);
        $(this).after(newSpan);
        makeBtn($(this).next("span.w"));
        makeDropText($(this).next("span.w"));
        $("span.w.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      over: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      out: function() {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
    });
  }

  $("p.given").html(chunkWords($("p.given").text()));

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
});
```

```css
p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p.given span.w span.ui-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers>b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <p class="given" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1">the Santee, thDakota</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2">America</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3">Qatar</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4">Philippines</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

This takes the current text in the `<p>` and wraps each word with a No Break Space. It tries to adhere to sentence syntax.

Now that each word is wrapped we can then make each one droppable. This assumes a word will be drop on the preceding word and highlights the two words it would drop in between. Once dropped, a new `<span>` is created and appended after the target. I added a 'x' button to remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem is when I try to drop a dropable component as a first word of the  paragraph I'm unable to do it, can you please suggest me a solution to sort it, anyway thank you very much for your support all the time

Comment: and the other problem is when I edit text by typing. suppose I typed two words, I cannot drop the dropable component between those two words. newly typed two words acting as one :(

Comment: @Adam you had asked how to drag and drop text into a paragraph and I answered that. You can run `$("p.given").html(chunkWords($("p.given").text()));` again at specific events to break up the new words typed in. If you need more help with that, I would advise marking an answer for this question, working on the new issue a bit and then if needed, ask another question.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll ask it on another question

Comment: Can you please look on this, I asked it as another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215677/drag-and-drop-span-to-paragraph-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Array with words.
2. Create new fragment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment#JavaScript
3. Iterate Array with forEach() and `append` every word with `<span data-index="indexNumber">arrayWord</span>` to fragment.
4. After iteration, append fragment to your `<p>`.
5. Then you get your Sentence with separate words.
6. Add data-dropped-value attribute to every span elements.
7. `on drop` dragged element you will update span, and it will be `data-dropped-value="your dragged value"`.
8. Then you can append this value to this span.

or

7. On drop append text to span, which is hovered.
8. Is don't needed

Comment: This might work yet would need to append a `<span>` after the current drop point. I don't think OP wants the dropped element or word to be a part of the current `<span>`.

Comment: Also, what happens when new text is typed in by the User?

Comment: @Twisty yeah, your right sir. that are the problems

Comment: maybe append input on click event could help, click on span, get event.target and then append input. but you need to change your `p` and `span` to `div`, because of semantic, I think

Comment: Input should be the best solution. Then you can just handle drop on input and add value. So it will be writable and droppable.