# CSS display: flex; not working properly in IE browser

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm using Jquery draggable component to add an element to `<p>`.

**I have following issue**

IE browser showing bad look(see the image) It shows `all-scroll` instead of `Pointer`

[image]

**this happens because of this CSS**

```
p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

this CSS I used to display the `<p>` content properly. If I remove that CSS, draggable component adding multiple places to sometimes. and also `<p>` contents going to the next lines after drop components. Can you suggest anything instead of `flex`? I can't remove this CSS (`p.given { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }`), because if I remove that `<p>` content not flexible properly, So please give me a solution to avoid this IE browser issue.

```js
$(function() {
  function textWrapper(str, sp, btn) {
    if (sp == undefined) {
      sp = [0, 0];
    }
    var txt = "";
    if (btn) {
      txt = "<span class='w b'>" + str + "</span>";
    } else {
      txt = "<span class='w'>" + str + "</span>";
    }

    if (sp[0]) {
      txt = "&nbsp;" + txt;
    }

    if (sp[1]) {
      txt = txt + "&nbsp;";
    }

    return txt;
  }

  function chunkWords(p) {
    var words = p.split(" ");
    words[0] = textWrapper(words[0], [0, 1]);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
      var re = /\[.+\]/;
      if (re.test(words[i])) {
        var b = makeTextBox(words[i].slice(1, -1));
        words[i] = "&nbsp;" + b.prop("outerHTML") + "&nbsp;";
      } else {
        if (words[0].indexOf(".")) {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 0]);
        } else {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 1]);
        }
      }
    }
    return words.join("");
  }

  function unChunkWords(tObj) {
    var words = [];
    $(".w", tObj).each(function(i, el) {
      console.log($(el).text(), $(el).attr("class"));
      if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
        words.push("[" + $(el).text().trim() + "]");
      } else {
        words.push($(el).text().trim());
      }
    });
    return words.join(" ");
  }

  function makeBtn(tObj) {
    var btn = $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
    }).appendTo(tObj);
  }

  function makeTextBox(txt) {
    var sp = $("<span>", {
      class: "w b"
    }).html(txt);
    makeBtn(sp);
    return sp;
  }

  function makeDropText(obj) {
    return obj.droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var txt = ui.draggable.text();
        var newSpan = textWrapper(txt, [1, 0], 1);
        $(this).after(newSpan);
        makeBtn($(this).next("span.w"));
        makeDropText($(this).next("span.w"));
        $("span.w.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      over: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      out: function() {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
    });
  }

  $("p.given").html(chunkWords($("p.given").text()));

  $("p.given").on("click", ".b > .ui-icon", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $("p.given").blur(function() {
    var w = unChunkWords($(this));
    console.log(w);
    $(this).html(chunkWords(w));
    makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
  });

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
});
```

```css
p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p.given span.w span.ui-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers>b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <p class="given" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. [Lorem] Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1">the Santee, thDakota</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2">America</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3">Qatar</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4">Philippines</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: When using CSS3 properties and supporting IE, you need to be aware of the limitations that such old browsers have. Flexbox alone is only partially supported in IE 10 and 11...  See [flexbox on Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, why support IE? It's a very old browser that has many issues particularly in development. I also noticed that you use jQuery 1.12.4 and jQueryUI 1.12.1. Again, they are old versions that makes your code slow and possibly insecure.

As for the solution, the problem lies in contentEditable option. Once removed the cursor appears normal on IE11.

I never thought I would say this but: I tested on IE11 and it worked normally

Here is the new code:

> based on the comment I added a new function that checks if use clicked on p element then sets contenteditable to true, otherwise it will set it to false. This is less than ideal on IE but I think this is the most you can get out of that browser.

```js
$(function() {
  function textWrapper(str, sp, btn) {
    if (sp == undefined) {
      sp = [0, 0];
    }
    var txt = "";
    if (btn) {
      txt = "<span class='w b'>" + str + "</span>";
    } else {
      txt = "<span class='w'>" + str + "</span>";
    }

    if (sp[0]) {
      txt = "&nbsp;" + txt;
    }

    if (sp[1]) {
      txt = txt + "&nbsp;";
    }

    return txt;
  }

  function chunkWords(p) {
    var words = p.split(" ");
    words[0] = textWrapper(words[0], [0, 1]);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
      var re = /\[.+\]/;
      if (re.test(words[i])) {
        var b = makeTextBox(words[i].slice(1, -1));
        words[i] = "&nbsp;" + b.prop("outerHTML") + "&nbsp;";
      } else {
        if (words[0].indexOf(".")) {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 0]);
        } else {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 1]);
        }
      }
    }
    return words.join("");
  }

  function unChunkWords(tObj) {
    var words = [];
    $(".w", tObj).each(function(i, el) {
      console.log($(el).text(), $(el).attr("class"));
      if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
        words.push("[" + $(el).text().trim() + "]");
      } else {
        words.push($(el).text().trim());
      }
    });
    return words.join(" ");
  }

  function makeBtn(tObj) {
    var btn = $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
    }).appendTo(tObj);
  }

  function makeTextBox(txt) {
    var sp = $("<span>", {
      class: "w b"
    }).html(txt);
    makeBtn(sp);
    return sp;
  }

  function makeDropText(obj) {
    return obj.droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var txt = ui.draggable.text();
        var newSpan = textWrapper(txt, [1, 0], 1);
        $(this).after(newSpan);
        makeBtn($(this).next("span.w"));
        makeDropText($(this).next("span.w"));
        $("span.w.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      over: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      out: function() {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
    });
  }

  $("p.given").html(chunkWords($("p.given").text()));

  $("p.given").on("click", ".b > .ui-icon", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $("p.given").blur(function() {
    var w = unChunkWords($(this));
    console.log(w);
    $(this).html(chunkWords(w));
    makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
  });

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
  /**
   * New function. Check document click event and see if use clicked
   * inside or outside the p.given element then set contenteditable
   * accordingly.
   */
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    let pElement = jQuery(e.target).closest("p.given");
    let check = !$(event.target).is("p.given") && !$(event.target).parents("p.given").is("p.given");

    if (check) {
      $("p.given").attr("contenteditable", "false");
    } else {
      $("p.given").attr("contenteditable", "true").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p.given span.w span.ui-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers>b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <p class="given" contenteditable="false">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. [Lorem] Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1">the Santee, thDakota</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2">America</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3">Qatar</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4">Philippines</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: _Firstly, why support IE?_ Because you deal with a client, a company for example which uses it exclusively. I work on a project which recently (a couple of month) switched from IE11 Enterprise mode (=IE8 engine) to IE11 default mode. It was very hard to convince them to drop Enterprise Mode.

Comment: @Kalimah Apps Thank you very much for your answer, but now the problem is I can't type text inside `<p>` (by manually). I need that functionality also :)

Comment: @Kalimah Apps I checked it, after your change again previous behaviour occuring in IE 11. (showing all-scroll).

Comment: @KalimahApps Okay its doesn't matter. thank you very much for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I just inspected the DOM and found the selectors that best suited the desired result.

Here are the classes for manipulating the cursor.

```css
.w.b.ui-droppable {
  cursor: pointer; /* The dropped text */
}

.given.btn-flat.ui-draggable {
  cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: grab; /* Text to be dropped */
}

.given.btn-flat.ui-draggable-dragging {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing; cursor: grabbing; /* Text being dragged */
}
```

If you need more help with styling cursors, you can check out the documentation:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

### Example

Not sure about your custom class names e.g. `given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1`, but I did not need them in this case.

```js
$(function() {
  function textWrapper(str, sp, btn) {
    if (sp == undefined) {
      sp = [0, 0];
    }
    var txt = "";
    if (btn) {
      txt = "<span class='w b'>" + str + "</span>";
    } else {
      txt = "<span class='w'>" + str + "</span>";
    }
    if (sp[0]) {
      txt = "&nbsp;" + txt;
    }
    if (sp[1]) {
      txt = txt + "&nbsp;";
    }
    return txt;
  }

  function chunkWords(p) {
    var words = p.split(" ");
    words[0] = textWrapper(words[0], [0, 1]);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
      var re = /\[.+\]/;
      if (re.test(words[i])) {
        var b = makeTextBox(words[i].slice(1, -1));
        words[i] = "&nbsp;" + b.prop("outerHTML") + "&nbsp;";
      } else {
        if (words[0].indexOf(".")) {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 0]);
        } else {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 1]);
        }
      }
    }
    return words.join("");
  }

  function unChunkWords(tObj) {
    var words = [];
    $(".w", tObj).each(function(i, el) {
      //console.log($(el).text(), $(el).attr("class"));
      if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
        words.push("[" + $(el).text().trim() + "]");
      } else {
        words.push($(el).text().trim());
      }
    });
    return words.join(" ");
  }

  function makeBtn(tObj) {
    var btn = $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
    }).appendTo(tObj);
  }

  function makeTextBox(txt) {
    var sp = $("<span>", {
      class: "w b"
    }).html(txt);
    makeBtn(sp);
    return sp;
  }

  function makeDropText(obj) {
    return obj.droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var txt = ui.draggable.text();
        var newSpan = textWrapper(txt, [1, 0], 1);
        $(this).after(newSpan);
        makeBtn($(this).next("span.w"));
        makeDropText($(this).next("span.w"));
        $("span.w.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      over: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      out: function() {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
    });
  }

  $("p.given").html(chunkWords($("p.given").text()));

  $("p.given").on("click", ".b > .ui-icon", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $("p.given").blur(function() {
    var w = unChunkWords($(this));
    console.log(w);
    $(this).html(chunkWords(w));
    makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
  });

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
});
```

```css
p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p.given span.w span.ui-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers>b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}

.w.ui-droppable {
  /* All other text */
}

.w.b.ui-droppable {
  background: #FF8;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.given.btn-flat.ui-draggable {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #A72020;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: grab;
}

.given.btn-flat.ui-draggable-dragging {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing; cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <p class="given" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. [Lorem] Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1">the Santee, thDakota</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2">America</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3">Qatar</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4">Philippines</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I had to update my question correctly in order to my issue, So please look on this or update your answer, otherwise someone misunderstand this answer, I'm really sorry , Thank you

Comment: @Adam Not sure if I understand entirely, but I updated the response above.

Comment: Nope, Your not got my point, I used this CSS part  `p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}` to work my code properly , this is works fine in firefox & chrome broswers, but in IE browser showing bad look with that, see the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9VGz.png) . I can't remove that CSS part beacuse if I remove it, when the drag and dropping paragrapgh content not flexible properly , so pls if you can run the code with IE browser,then you can take what I'm saying here

Comment: Please see my updated question, so u can take idea what I'm saying here, thanks sir