# How to avoid removing typed text from contenteditable <p> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, contenteditable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery UI draggable component to add `<span>` to content editable `<p>`.

The expected output was, paragraph `<p>` should be editable and the draggable component should able to drag and drop to paragraph and also the content of the `<p>` should able to be editable. I have problems with my code. When I type something inside `<p>` and click the outside `<p>`. typed words removing from the paragraph.

My code as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  function textWrapper(str, sp, btn) {
    if (sp == undefined) {
      sp = [0, 0];
    }
    var txt = "";
    if (btn) {
      txt = "<span class='w b'>" + str + "</span>";
    } else {
      txt = "<span class='w'>" + str + "</span>";
    }

    if (sp[0]) {
      txt = "&nbsp;" + txt;
    }

    if (sp[1]) {
      txt = txt + "&nbsp;";
    }

    return txt;
  }

  function chunkWords(p) {
    var words = p.split(" ");
    words[0] = textWrapper(words[0], [0, 1]);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
      var re = /\[.+\]/;
      if (re.test(words[i])) {
        var b = makeTextBox(words[i].slice(1, -1));
        words[i] = "&nbsp;" + b.prop("outerHTML") + "&nbsp;";
      } else {
        if (words[0].indexOf(".")) {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 0]);
        } else {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 1]);
        }
      }
    }
    return words.join("");
  }

  function unChunkWords(tObj) {
    var words = [];
    $(".w", tObj).each(function(i, el) {
      console.log($(el).text(), $(el).attr("class"));
      if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
        words.push("[" + $(el).text().trim() + "]");
      } else {
        words.push($(el).text().trim());
      }
    });
    return words.join(" ");
  }

  function makeBtn(tObj) {
    var btn = $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
    }).appendTo(tObj);
  }

  function makeTextBox(txt) {
    var sp = $("<span>", {
      class: "w b"
    }).html(txt);
    makeBtn(sp);
    return sp;
  }

  function makeDropText(obj) {
    return obj.droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var txt = ui.draggable.text();
        var newSpan = textWrapper(txt, [1, 0], 1);
        $(this).after(newSpan);
        makeBtn($(this).next("span.w"));
        makeDropText($(this).next("span.w"));
        $("span.w.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      over: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      out: function() {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
    });
  }

  $("p.given").html(chunkWords($("p.given").text()));

  $("p.given").on("click", ".b > .ui-icon", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $("p.given").blur(function() {
    var w = unChunkWords($(this));
    console.log(w);
    $(this).html(chunkWords(w));
    makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
  });

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
});
```

```css
p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p.given span.w span.ui-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers>b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <p class="given" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. [Lorem] Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1">the Santee, thDakota</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2">America</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3">Qatar</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4">Philippines</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

The problem occurs intermittently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the user-entered text is removed again, and the cause is in the function `unChunkWords`:

This function iterates only over *elements* (with class "w"), but it does not iterate over the plain text nodes that may occur in-between those elements. And in a content-editable element, the user can indeed type text in areas *between* elements. And so this loop in `unChunkWords` will never visit such text, omitting it in the array it returns.

You can force it to happen by putting the cursor at the end of a word, before a space, then press the right arrow key. Either this moves the cursor to the start of the next word, or it does not move visibly (it just moved out of the `span` it was in). Either way, your cursor is now in the text node that separates the two words. Type something and click somewhere else. ... the anomaly happens.

There are many ways to circumvent this. One of them is to use the jQuery `contents()` method, which also collects text nodes. Change the following code:

```
$(".w", tObj).each(function(i, el) {
  if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
    words.push("[" + $(el).text().trim() + "]");
  } else {
    words.push($(el).text().trim());
  }
});
```

...to this:

```
$(tObj).contents().each(function (i, el) {
  if (el.nodeType !== 3 && !$(el).is(".w")) return; // Only regard ".w" or text nodes
  if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
    words.push("[" + $(el).text().trim() + "]");
  } else {
    words.push($(el).text().trim());
  }
});
```

Now the text you enter will not be omitted from `words`, even when you type it in text nodes that are direct children of the content-editable element.

#### Adding spaces

Your code is adding spaces with `.join(" ")` without verifying that the text fragments are really separated by white space in the content of the `p` element. So, I would just grab *all* content, including spacing and just concatenate that. That way you will have the word separations exactly as they are in the `p` element.

So then your function would be:

```
  function unChunkWords(tObj) {
    var words = "";
    $(tObj).contents().each(function (i, el) {
      if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
        words += "[" + $(el).text() + "]";
      } else {
        words += $(el).text();
      }
    });
    return words.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  }
```

*Disclaimer:* I have only looked at this *particular* problem, pointing out why you have this *particular* behaviour, and how to fix it. This does not mean that now your code will work correctly in all its intended functionality, which would go beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @rincot Thanks sir, It solved, but when click the `<p>` and click the outside of the `<p>` whitespaces making between each words. how to avoid it?

Comment: and one more thing, I want to change the color of draggable components color **when dragging time** how to do it ?

Comment: and why internet explorer showing this appearance. it shows all-scroll when mouse hover the `<p>` https://i.imgur.com/Vo2Btk9.png

Comment: These are all different questions. Could you please post a new question, and focus on one question only? I would be happy to look at it/them when you do.

Comment: But sir fisrt issue (`when click the <p> and click the outside of the <p> whitespaces making between each words`) is previously worked one. :) can you please help me to solve that. other two issues I'll post seperatly.thanks  ur support, and words :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean? You are always inserting spaces between words? Is that not what you want?

Comment: no sir I need to drag and drop dragablle components to `<p>` paragrapgh, as well as I need edit paragraph content manually(by typing things) , problem is now 95% solved and code works fine, but each time I click inside `<p>` and click the outside, spaces are adding between each words. I only need add one space between each word (as normal paragraph)

Comment: In my question's code, now I'm telling the issue is not in there, the previous problem was typed content removing when I click outside the `<p>` . you gave me a solution to it and its works now, but now the problem is when clicking the `<p>` and click the outside multiple spaces are generating between words.

Comment: Just to complete: the issue was already there in your code: when you delete a space between two words, joining them, they get separated again (because of the `.join(" ")` in your code. So really this is a different problem. But anyway, I added a section on that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir, u are great :) can u please look on this issue. As u said I asked it seperatly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491953/change-the-color-of-draggable-item-when-dragging-jquery

Comment: Okay sure sir. Thanks for ur suppot, I'm suppose all my code works fine now, I tested and looks okay :) If I face anything in future, please help me :) and can you please explain what happen insed these function, because I got this code from internet and i don't have much idea about the code, if u have time please put a comment each methods  `textWrapper(), chunkWords(), unChunkWords(), makeTextBox(), makeDropText()` I'm a student, so ur help will be helped to me lot sir

Comment: I honestly do not have time to try to make sense of that code. It is also off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you really want to get comments about the code, then try on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but make sure you first read the help section there to see what you can ask about.

Comment: Okay thanks anyway sir :) can you please look my other problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491953/ie-browser-showing-all-scroll-instead-of-pointer .

And I have one little thing to ask from you. I need to get the text of `<p>` like this `Lorem [Ipsum] is simply [dummy] ` this output returns `unChunkWords` method in blur event. How can I get that output when button click. when button click have any possible way to pass `<p>` object to function `unChunkWords` ?

Comment: You can do what you want on a click event. Just add the handler with `$("p.given").click(function ......` etc. If you have a question about that, don't ask it in comments, but post a new question. This comment section is only intended for clarification about the current question and answer ;-)

Comment: okay sir, but I ask u, how can I pass `<p>` object to `unChunkWords() ` words when another button click, anyway sir, can u please look this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491953/ie-browser-showing-all-scroll-instead-of-pointer

Comment: You can pass it just same way as the `blur` event handler does it. But please, don't keep asking questions here. If you have a problem implementing such a thing, then ask a new question via the standard way on this site.

Comment: okay understood sir, sorry for my mad, can u please look on this sir, no one care about  that :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491953/ie-browser-showing-all-scroll-instead-of-pointer , this problem occurs in IE browser

Comment: sir I have a problem related to this, I cant drag and drop element as a first to the paragraph. have any possible way to do it

Comment: Have you posted it as a new question?

Comment: no sir, I'm really sorry about  that, do I need to do it :(

Comment: I asked new quetion sir, can u please look on that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822882/cannot-drag-and-drop-draggable-component-as-first-word

Comment: can u please look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822882/cannot-drag-and-drop-draggable-component-as-first-word