# Why does the promise resolve?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code:

```
class Request {
  constructor(method, url) {
    this.method = method;
    this.url = url;
  }

  send() {
    return fetch(this.url, { method: this.method })
      .then((res) => res.json());
  }
}

const url = "https://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes";
const getQuotes = new Request("get", url);

const all = {
  getQuotes
};

getQuotes.send().then(alert);
delete all.getQuotes;
```

Can somebody, please, explain why does `getQuotes.send()` resolve even after I have explicitly deleted a class instance on which the promise was executed.

Comment: not sure about that, but `.json` returns your json object not a promise, so, the `then` here `getQuotes.send().then(alert);` does not seems to work

Comment: you are deleting it from the object, does nothing to the request.

Comment: All `delete all.getQuotes` does is remove `getQuotes` as a property from the `all` object.  It doesn't affect anything in the `getQuotes` request at all.  `delete` in Javascript doesn't actually delete an object.  In this particular usage, it just removes a property from the parent object.  The object you're calling delete on still exists just fine until it's done and is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

You have deleted the *reference* to the `Request` instance from the `all` object. I.e. removed the `getQuotes` property. The `getQuotes` const defined previously is still there and the promise is still running.

Comment: "promise is still running". Promises don't run. They can be pending. They can change state and be resolved or rejected... But they don't run. They are objects.

Comment: Good point. The code encapsulated by the promise is running, though :)

Comment: The code you refer to is not encapsulated by the promise. And it is not running either. The only thing that is running is the JavaScript event loop, and some lower level OS processing that is dealing with the request. JavaScript will receive some event from it in its queue that will call an implementation in the `fetch` API that will resolve the promise that was returned by the `fetch` function. But as long as that event is not coming in, nothing is running in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you run promise by `.then((res) => res.json());` (inside `send()`, and also further by `.then(alert)`). By the way: when you execute code

```
const getQuotes = new Request("get", url);
const all = { getQuotes };
```

then you request object is in two places: in `getQuotes` constant, and in `all.getQuotes` object field. So when you executed `delete all.getQuotes`, the `getQuotes` constant is still not empty (but this is not reason of promise execution).

Comment: can u pls look on this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527619/how-to-avoid-removing-typed-text-from-contenteditable-p-in-jquery